# Count value not increasing

Tags: python

I have a python file  called `myGlobal.py`, in this file I declared `count` as a global variable.

```
import datetime
import time
import os

count = 0
failCount = 0

def counterstart:
    global count
    count +=1
```

I am calling this counter in another file. So every time I call a function, I want the counter to increase by 1. That file is `scripts.py`

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
import time
from myGlobal import *

def main():
   fnfirst()
   fnsecond()
   fnthird()

def fnfirst(): 
    global count
    print count

def fnsecond(): 
    global count
    print count

def fnthird(): 
    global count
    print count

main()
```

But whenever I run `script.py`, the count is shown as 0 only.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You have two *different* `count`s, as each module has its own `global`s.

Comment: `from foo import *` is not good practice, better use `import foo` and then `foo.count`. This will probably also solve that problem you have.

Comment: I would rather use a singleton to store global variables so you don't have to keep on using the `global var` syntax everywhere

Comment: Aren't you getting a SyntaxError for this line `def counterstart:`? Is that method being called anywhere? If not, I don't see why you expect that `count` to increase.

Comment: `count=0;failCount=0;` looks like `C`, not python :)

Comment: You never run `counterstart`, so why would it be incrementing?

Comment: exactly, and `def counterstart:` gives you a syntax error anyway

Comment: yea so where i need to call 'counterstart'

Comment: @harimadhav We can talk more in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86989/room-for-superbiasedman-and-hari-madhav)

Answer (score 0):

```
import myGlobal

print myGlobal.count # 0
myGlobal.count += 1

def foo():
    myGlobal.count += 1

foo()
print myGlobal.count # 2
```

---

So here is a solution based on the Python's decorators. It will count the number of call on specific functions :

```
# File script.py

import myGlobal

def count_call(func):
    def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        myGlobal.count += 1
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapper

@count_call
def fnfirst():
    pass # do something

@count_call
def fnsecond():
    pass # do something

def main():
    print myGlobal.count # 0
    fnfirst()
    print myGlobal.count # 1
    fnsecond()
    print myGlobal.count # 2
    fnfirst()
    print myGlobal.count # 3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: no in scripts.py each is aa independent function, i dont want to call it again. Whenever i add a new function and call the global count, it should increase by 1. so if 5 functions, when i add 6th function and call count, it should print 6. but not working :-(

Comment: Eddited. Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: @harimadhav Are you saying here that `count` should count the number of functions that there are or the number of times functions are called?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan : The count should show number of functions that are called.

Comment: @harimadhav If one function is called 2 time, should `count` be incremented 2 times ?

Comment: @harimadhav Check the edit. (woops forgot a return. Fixed.)

Comment: @FunkySayu : please check ur gmail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86988/discussion-between-hari-madhav-and-funkysayu).